# Loading images list from sub directories of document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have set of images in iphone document directory,

Eg:

document_directory/sub_directory_1/sub directory_2

So how to retrieve all images from sub directory_2 as a NSArray or some sort of a data structure.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the path as a NSString*, use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
for (NSString *fileName in [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:NULL]) {
  NSLog(@"Found file %@", fileName);
}
```